# Is there an equivalent annotation for OnDelete in JPA2

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDelete;

@OnDelete(action = org.hibernate.annotations.OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
List<Foo> foos;
```

Is there an equivalent JPA2 annotation for the Hibernate annotation OnDelete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.Delete)`. Thus the cascade will be handled by the orm (hibernate), and not the database. If you want to have a cascade generated in the DB, the hibernate-specific annotation is the only way.

Comment: I already have cascase = CascadeType.ALL as part of my @OneToMany annotation and @OnDelete annotation was needed in Hibernate 3.3.x. Are you saying that I can remove this annotation safely and expect the deletes to be cascaded?

Comment: If I remove the @OnDelete annotation, the "on delete cascade" constraint is not being generated as part of the generated sql. I guess this is incorrect.

Comment: @Joe true. The cascade is not handled by the DB, it is handled by hibernate only. It is expected behaviour.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I don't need the @OnDelete annotation, but Hibernate will still go ahead and remove my child deletions in a cascade fashion if cascade is set to ALL.

Comment: @Joe - yes. However, if you want to use your DB with something other than hibernate as well, you should need the OnDelete. I also don't like the fact that hibernate doesn't generate that for cascade=DELETE