# Hibernate: OnDelete vs cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE

Tags: database, hibernate, jpa, annotations

What is the difference between `@OnDelete(action=OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)` and `cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE`

I read here: [Is there an equivalent annotation for OnDelete in JPA2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393866/is-there-an-equivalent-annotation-for-ondelete-in-jpa2)
that with `@OnDelete(action=OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)` the cascade will be handled by the DB, while with `cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE` the cascade will be handled by the ORM (Hibernate).

1. Could you explain what is the difference between handling by Hibernate vs handling by the DB? **How is it done "by the DB"?**
2. Also, **I would like to know why should I care about the difference.** I mean, why should I choose one attitude over the other.
3. Last question is, looking at the [OnDelete javadoc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/annotations/OnDelete.html) I was wondering why it says nothing about what is does and why I should use it (BTW where is the inheritance path?). So where are these points documented?

Answer (score 2):

1-Some database support cascade option and some databases do  not :If the database  support cascade  then hibernate will create schema  accordingly and let database to handle cascading.

2-If database handle cascade use it ,other vice hibernate have to query database and this is a performance lost.

3-No idea