# JPA's cascade = REMOVE and Hibernate's @OnDelete used together?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have inherited a code base on which nearly all relations have the following annotations:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.REMOVE }, mappedBy = "someThing")
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
```

Now I'm having trouble understanding what `@OnDelete` does in the first place. [Hibernate: OnDelete vs cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948297/hibernate-ondelete-vs-cascade-cascadetype-remove) is interesting, but unfortunately doesn't have any answers and the JavaDoc for `@OnDelete` is particularly worthless.

From the other questions it looks like the OnDelete annotation somehow lets the DB do the cascading, while the cascading directive on `@OneToMany` let's the ORM do it, but what would ever be the purpose of using them together?

And does `@OneToMany`'s cascade directive really doesn't allow the ORM implementation to generate a DB based cascade anyway?

Answer (score 28):

Let's say you have a one-to-one directional relationship

```
class House {

    @OneToOne
    Object door;

}
```

If you use CascadeType.REMOVE then deleting the house will also delete the door.

```
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE)
    Object door;
```

If you use @OnDelete then deleting the door will also delete the house.

```
    @OneToOne
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    Object door;
```

Read more here: https://rogerkeays.com/jpa-cascadetype-remove-vs-hibernate-ondelete

Comment: The behaviour with a `@OneToOne` and a `@OneToMany` doesn't seem to be quite the same. With `@OneToMany(...) @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE) Object doors`, it seems that deleting the house delete all its doors, but deleting a door doesn't delete the house.

Comment: It would have to be `@OneToMany List<Object> doors`, I think. But besides that, this mapping wouldn't normally create a column on the House table. You'd either have a reverse mapping on `Doors.house`, or a collection table. For database cascading, I think the column has to be in the table you want to cascade into.

Comment: Disagree. I think the the biggest difference between ```CascadeType.REMOVE``` and ```@OnDelete``` in user's view is that ```@OnDelete``` can work with JPAQL (since it is based on DB cascade), but ```CascadeType.REMOVE``` can not work with JPAQL.

Comment: '@OnDelete's purpose is to delegate the delete of related objects via the databases foreignkey contraints. You can achive the same by using @Cascade ragarding to your example