# Hibernate refuses to generate tables with OnDelete annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa, annotations

When I'm trying to apply @OnDelete(action=OnDeleteAction.CASCADE) and generate tables with hibernate nothing happens. With attribute OrhpanRemoval=true hibernate generates tables, but still refuses to cascade delete entities.

Table itself joined to another table with @OneToMany annotation. The tables are bellow:

```
 @Entity
       @Table(name = "Style")
       public class Style {

        public Style() {

        }

        public Style(String nameRus, String nameEng) {
            this.nameRus = nameRus;
            this.nameEng = nameEng;
        }

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "style_id")
        private Long id;

        @Column(name = "Style_Name_rus", nullable = false)
        private String nameRus;

        @Column(name = "Style_Name_eng", nullable = false)
        private String nameEng;

        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinTable(name = "Styles_Songs", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "style_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "song_id"))
        @OnDelete(action=OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
        private Set<Song> songs;

        public Set<Song> getSongs() {
            return songs;
        }

        public void setSongs(Set<Song> songs) {
            this.songs = songs;
        }

        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getNameRus() {
            return nameRus;
        }

        public void setNameRus(String nameRus) {
            this.nameRus = nameRus;
        }

        public String getNameEng() {
            return nameEng;
        }
    public void setNameEng(String nameEng) {
        this.nameEng = nameEng;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.nameRus;
    }
}
```

Table #2:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Song")
public class Song {

    public Song() {

    }

    public Song(String name, String performer, String trackLength, Style style,
            User user) {
        this.name = name;
        this.performer = performer;
        this.style = style;
        this.trackLength = trackLength;
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "song_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "Song_name", nullable=false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "Performer", nullable=false)
    private String performer;

    @Column(name = "Track_length", nullable=false)
    private String trackLength;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "style_id", nullable=false)
    private Style style;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable=false)
    private User user;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name="Commentaries",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="song_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="comment_id")
    )
    private Set<Commentary> commentaries;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPerformer() {
        return performer;
    }

    public void setPerformer(String performer) {
        this.performer = performer;
    }

    public String getTrackLength() {
        return trackLength;
    }

    public void setTrackLength(String trackLength) {
        this.trackLength = trackLength;
    }

    public Style getStyle() {
        return style;
    }

    public void setStyle(Style style) {
        this.style = style;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return this.performer+" - "+this.name;
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: So it works without this specific annotation ?

Comment: Yes, it works fine. However, I want to make a cascade entity deletion, and I can't figure how to do so without it.

Comment: Well I was intrigued by the `@OnDelete` with the `Cascade.ALL` (on the `@OneToMany`), so I looked around a bit and I found that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563592/jpas-cascade-remove-and-hibernates-ondelete-used-together. It seems to have help the other guy

Comment: He's having trouble with understanding the @OnDelete annotation, not with annotation itself, database, or hibernate. There isn't anything helping on that part

Comment: `orphanRemoval=true` perhaps? Why do you *need* the database to do this, when you can get Hibernate to do it for you?

Comment: With attribute OrhpanRemoval=true hibernate generates tables, but still refuses to cascade delete entities.