# Hibernate default behaviour when deleting entities with related records

Tags: hibernate, constraints, one-to-many, delete-row

I have a simple one to many relationship like so:

Entity Customer:

```
...
@OneToMany(targetEntity = Ticket.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
public Collection<Ticket> getTickets() {
    return tickets;
}
```

Entity Ticket

```
....
@ManyToOne
public Customer getCustomer() {
    return customer;
}
```

When I delete a customer entity that has related records in Ticket, Hibernate will 'null' customer_id in Ticket for these records and delete the customer.
This bypasses the existing ON DELETE RESTRICT constraint on the FK on customer_id.

I want Hibernate to throw an exception rather than nulling customer_id in related records.
How can I achieve that?
I thought this should be default behaviour but this seems to be not the case

Comment: Use The Hibernate specific non-JPA compliant `@OnDelete` annotation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563592/jpas-cascade-remove-and-hibernates-ondelete-used-together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself:
The reason for this behaviour is a mapping error. The @JoinColumn must be defined in the owned entity (Ticket) while the owning entity (Customer) must define 'mappedBy'.

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
public Customer getCustomer() {

....

@OneToMany(targetEntity = Ticket.class, mappedBy = "id")
public Set<Ticket> getTickets() {
    return tickets;
}
```